# How do I count the number of occurrences of a charSequence in a String in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

For Example if this is my equation string,

```
IF(AND(x>0,x<100),5,IF(AND(x>101,x<200),6,10))
```

I want to count the no:of occurrences of "IF(" string in the equation.

Answer (score 22):

E.g. this way:

```
def s = "IF(AND(x>0,x<100),5,IF(AND(x>101,x<200),6,10))"
assert 2 == s.count("IF(")
```

In more advanced example you would probably need to use regex.